# Center JDialog over JPanel on JTabbedPane

Tags: java, swing, centering, jdialog

I have tried all of the suggestions I found here and on other sites.

I can't seem to get this JDialog to be centered over the panel on the JTabbedPane.

Please note, I must have the close button disabled, so I can not use the standard JOptionPane.showDialogXYZ() methods.

Any ideas?

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class CenterDialog extends JFrame
{
    public CenterDialog()
    {
        setResizable(false);

        setName(getClass().getSimpleName());
        setTitle("My Frame");
        setSize(300, 300);

        JTabbedPane tabbedPane = new JTabbedPane(JTabbedPane.TOP);

        // Add the panel
        tabbedPane.addTab("Button panel", new MyButtonPanel());

        add(tabbedPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        getContentPane().add(tabbedPane);
    }

    private class MyButtonPanel extends JPanel
    {

        public MyButtonPanel()
        {
            JButton btnShowDialog = new JButton("Show Dialog");
            btnShowDialog.addActionListener(new BtnShowDialogActionListener());
            add(btnShowDialog);
        }

        private class BtnShowDialogActionListener implements ActionListener
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                // TODO: Figure out how to center this dialog box
                final String YES = "Yup";
                final String NO = "Nope";
                final Object[] options = { YES, NO };

                final JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane("Is this centered.", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE,
                        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION, null, options, NO);

                Frame f = JOptionPane.getFrameForComponent(((JButton) e.getSource()).getParent());
                final JDialog dialog = new JDialog(f, "Question", ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);

                dialog.setContentPane(optionPane);
                dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);

                dialog.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter()
                {
                    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Ignoring close button");
                    }
                });

                optionPane.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener()
                {
                    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e)
                    {
                        String prop = e.getPropertyName();

                        if (dialog.isVisible() && (e.getSource() == optionPane))
                        {
                            if (prop.equals(JOptionPane.VALUE_PROPERTY))
                            {
                                dialog.setVisible(false);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

                dialog.pack();
                dialog.setVisible(true);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        // Create and set up the window.
        CenterDialog frame = new CenterDialog();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    createAndShowGUI();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  Regardless of which Component I used for relativeTo,  dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(relativeTo) did not center the dialog properly.

I then took the source for Window.setLocationRelativeTo() and placed it in my class so I was able to debug it properly.  Turns out, the problem is that dialog.getBounds() is called and returns (0,0) because the dialog was not packed yet.  Since it was not packed, it had no dimensions - this messed up the math in setLocationRelativeTo().  The solution, call dialog.pack() first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The method which centers a dialog relative to a given component (no manual calculation needed, handles component-to-screen coordinate mapping internally):

```
  dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(someComponent);
```

Choose the component, depending on what exactly you want to achieve:

```
 // center relative to the button
 dialog.setLocationRelativeTo((Component) e.getSource());

 // center relative to button's parent
 dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(((Component) e.getSource()).getParent());

 // center relative to the tabbedPane
 JTabbedPane tabbed = // walk the parent chain until you reach it
 dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(tabbed);
```

Answer (score 2):

I got slightly closer to what you're after by setting `tabbedPane` as global and then `dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(tabbedPane);`

Edit: a more elaborate, and probably visually accurate, solution is to calculate the x, y coordinates of your JDialog, something like this:

```
int xDiff = (tabbedPane.getWidth() - dialog.getWidth()) / 2;
int x = tabbedPane.getX() + xDiff;
int yDiff = (tabbedPane.getHeight() - dialog.getHeight()) / 2;
int y = tabbedPane.getY() + yDiff;
dialog.setLocation(x, y);
```

If I'm honest, I didn't get it working perfectly, but there's my theory!

Comment: hach .. have quit reading your pre-edit answer on hitting the "as global" :-) Which is neither wanted nor needed - simply walk the hierarchy up. As to the manual calculations: dialog location is in screen coordinates while the component location is relative to the container it lives in, so you first need to transform the latter to screen coordinates (see the source of setLocationRelativeTo ;-)

Comment: Agreed on the global bit, it was sort of a lazy workaround while I looked to get the location about right. I also had a feeling the tabbedPane was positioned relative to it's parent. If I'm honest, in my experimentation, I was being lazy (again) and using the JFrame's location for the maths, since the tabbedPane is nestled nice and tight up inside it ;) I should really have made mention to this in my reply >.< edit: in other words, +1 for your answer!